# Minimize/Maximze a function against its approximation.

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-optimization

Let $f \in C^{\infty}[1,2]$ be a function we would like to approximate, let be $g$ such approximation, you can assume $g$ is a spline function (at least quadratic). In literature I have seen that a bound is usually given in the approximation, however such bound hold "asymptotically" namely if $h$ is the mesh size in an uniform interpolation the bound given holds when $h \rightarrow 0$. So I was planning to find such max error using numerical optimization algorithms, however I don't have a big understanding, but I have literature I could consult... so I just need a clue on what technique could I look at. So how do I find

$$
\epsilon_M = \max_{x \in [1,2)} |f(x) - g(x)|
$$

My attempt, as algorithm design, would be:

1. Find the derivative $\left(f(x) - g(x)\right)'$.
2. Find all the solutions of the equation $\left(f(x) - g(x)\right)' = 0$, using newton raphson for example.
3. Say $\left\{x_k\right\}_k$ are such solutions, $\epsilon_M = \max_{k} |f(x_k) - g(x_k)|$

Further assumptions:

a. You can assume $f(x)$ is convex in $[1,2)$

b. The spline is interpolant, and assume degree is 2 or 3.

Comment: How will you calculate $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$? If you know their value everywhere, you don't need to interpolate, but if you don't know their value everywhere, you can't find $\max|f(x)-g(x)|$ for $x\in[1,2)$, only for the $x_i$ where $f(x_i)$ is defined.

Comment: I don't understand... is my statement of the problem ill posed? I have a function, I take samples of the function and then I interpolate such values, i have an error function and I want the max of the error function, what's wrong with that?

Comment: But $\epsilon_M$ is unlikely to occur at the points where you know what $f(x)$ is, so you can't compute the error function.

Comment: I still don't understand, you know what the expression $f(x)$ is so you know the value for each $x \in [1,2)$ then you take samples of such function, then I interpolate the function in such nodes with a spline function. So you both know $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. I didn't understand why you said that I don't need to interpolate, there could be different reasons why I could need to interpolate samples of a known function... but that wasn't my question. I was trying to give as much info as possible of my problem in order to help to classify my problem somehow.

Comment: Well in that case, yes, what you've proposed should work, if you can construct and find all solutions to $f'(x)-g'(x)$. Since $f(x)$ is convex though, it shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: Yes but the issue is... How can i be sure that I find all the solutions? Newton raphson would help me to find "A" solution in the interval, so in order to find all the solutions i should split the interval and apply newton raphson for each interval.. What I don't actually know is how should i split the interval properly.

Comment: For a convex function and quadratic/cubic interpolant, there can't be too many solutions, so the root finding should be feasible.

Comment: How can you be sure of that?